# Undeclared identifier error C2065 of definitions, that are clearly there

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, header-files

I am working with multiple projects, where I use header files of one project inside the other.

Now I added a project to the C/C++ Additional Include Directories, but after that I get this error with declarations that are all in the resource.h file.

My guess is that because both projects use a resource.h, it confuses them.
The resource.h files are different from each other.

So if it is this problem what can I do to stop this?

**Edit**: I'll try to make an example, since I can't post the original code here.

OK I got 2 Projects:

```
MixedMfc:
<-file1. cpp
<-file2. cpp
<-file3. cpp

<-file1.h
<-file2.h
<-file3.h
<-resource.h

NativeCaller:
<-file4.cpp
<-file5.cpp
<-file6.cpp

<-file4.h
<-file5.h
<-file6.h
<-resource.h
```

every header file has an `#include "resource.h"` (except the resource.h files)

the first resource.h looks like this:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
```

the second has a bunch of defines

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
#define VALUE1 1
#define VALUE2 2
#define VALUE3 3
#define VALUE4 4
#define VALUE5 5
```

Thanks

Comment: show your code or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like one project is picking up the resource.h of the other. Since they have the same name and are included the same way, you will have to do some experimenting with the compiler's include paths to make sure every file gets the right header. Or you could rename the file, but I'm not sure how well VS supports the resource header having a non-standard name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is often solved by setting a higher level directory as the Visual Studio include directory, and including files in the format of

```
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
```

or in your case

```
#include "project1/resource.h"
```

vs

```
#include "project2/resource.h"
```

Or are you just able to remove the empty resource.h from your project and delete it from your file system?